# What are the cyclic permutations on four symbols?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, permutation-cycles

I am trying to solve a problem of Hamermesh's Group Theory and its Applications to Physical Problems.

**Problem:** The cyclic permutations on four symbols form a subgroup $H$ of $S_4$. Resolve $S_4$ into left cosets with respect to $H$.

What are the cyclic permutation that form the subgroup $H$? I understand that it would be $(1234)$,$(1243)$,$(1342)$,$(1324)$,$(1432)$ and $(1423)$. But these don't form a subgroup as far as I understand. So I'm pretty sure that misunderstand what are the members of the subgroup $H$.

Can someone help me?

Comment: You are correct, it does not form a subgroup (even if we ignore that it doesn't include the identity, $(1234)^2=(13)(24)$). I wonder if it should be $S_5$? Then the cyclic permutations on five symbols, along with the identity, form a subgroup. (Also, I should say that I checked the book; the problem is on p22 and is as stated here. So there is no transcription issues on the part of the OP.)

Comment: I would guess that they are regarding $(1,3)(2,4)$ as being a cyclic permutation, because it moves each point two along.